# How will jbpm handle concurrent workflows in memory

Tags: workflow, drools, jbpm, workflowservice, robustness

I wanted to use jbpm as a library in my web service. Wanted to know the implementation details of how jbpm handles concurrent workflows in memory.

I want details with respect to scale , robustness

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So, your requirement is to run business processes in-memory only? For each instance you will have a separate process instance and you can have as many as your memory can handle. in jBPM there is an object called KieSession that keeps all the running process instances. In the case that you can to scale to multiple nodes you can have multiple KieSessions in each node.

Can you please elaborate more the question, if you are looking for more specific answers?

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have one question. If there are multiple "KieSession" objects in multiple instances running jbpm (possibly beind an ELB), how will they be in sync with the status of the ongoing process instance (which typically is in one of the instances)? How is it aware of the status (in between safe-points) of the process instance in some other machine?

Comment: They are coordinated through the database if you use persistent process instances. If you are running different process instances, they don't need to be coordinated. If they require coordination, most of the time means that they need to be persistent. But if your plan is to run non persistent process instances they will all be independent.